# Compiler Not Found

Tags: c++, macos

I am getting this error when i tried to compile my program

-bash: g++: command not found
Also I have only been getting this error after I formatted my Mac Book Pro
This error came after I did this

g++ functions.cpp

Please help me.
Thank You

Comment: You need to install [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) on your machine.

Comment: can you give me a link

Comment: I think you can complete this by installing Xcode

Comment: As @Mayerz says, you need to install Xcode, which will in turn install gcc and all the other developer tools you need.

Comment: do I need to install xcode to get gcc coz it is a very big file

Comment: ok thanks everyone i am downloading xcode now

Comment: If you only have a slow internet connection and you just want to do simple command line stuff then you can instead use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) to install gcc, but I would still recommend Xcode if possible.

Comment: i just saw that xcode requires 10.8.6 but i only have 10.7.5

Comment: @RahulNarayanan: Then use a older version of Xcode.

Comment: As @PaulR said, go to homebrew website, learn how to use it, install it, and then `homebrew install gcc`. I told you to install XCode because it would hav ebeen simpler IMO but the way to go is homebrew. (and the way I personnally use)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cleanest solution than installing XCode just for Gcc.

**STEP 1 >** install this:

> [HomeBrew Web Site] (http://brew.sh/)

All the informations concerning the installation and the utility of such a program are on the site itself.
It's a package manager, but for Mac. It's like *apt-get* or *yaourt*, if you ever used Ubuntu or Arch Linux.

---

**STEP 2 >** Go to the *Terminal* application and type :

```
$> homebrew search gcc
```

Then choose from the version you want, and type again in *Terminal*:

```
$> homebrew install [choosen version]
```

Gcc is now installed.

Comment: its asking me to download command line tools for installing anything with homebrew and i cant find the download anywhere

Comment: commands line tool? Can you give me more information, upload a screenshot on imgur.com or paste the logs here http://pastebin.com/ and give me a link?

Comment: Ok looks like you need to install Xcode (xcode-select --install)
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Installation

Comment: Your explanations are too broad and incomplete